# Passing text with special character in iOS URL scheme does break the url

Tags: iphone, ios, url

I'm trying to use my url scheme so that i can do `myapp://message=XXX`

Where `XXX` is the text to pass to my app.

The problem is that the link does not pass the text if it contain character like `éàü` and so on... the url breaks after `myapp://` Everything works fine without those character.

How can this be fixed?

Edit:

It cannot be fixed.

If the URL comes from another website, then there's actually nothing that can be done... unfortunately... afaik

Comment: So the link you mentioning is not in the format `<a href="myapp://message=XXX"/>` ?

Comment: Yes it's in this format. but I have no control over where this weblink can be put

Comment: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;` If you NSLog the `url`, what is the output?

Comment: it output myso:// and if there is some point in the string there is a / it will pursue with what goes next. for example "myapp://message=It's awesome & funny look www.website.com/hehe.png" will output 'myso:///hehe.png'

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` to percent encode the message.

Comment: the problem is the message comme from a link on a website for example it's cannot be treated before. The idea is that user click a link on a website and it will open the app with the text that should be shared on it thus it can be any text. I cant control it before it get accessible in the method

Comment: I would give you the up vote for being correct, and because I believe the downvote on your post is nonsensical. Too bad I'm out for the day!

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle nevermind, I'm here to the rescue. OP is being ignorant - *why couldn't* a dynamically created string be escaped, really?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle With 10k+ rep, I see the deleted posts :) So yes I did see it. And I also saw the exact same rude text having been proposed by the user John as an edit - I even made a screenshot of it. I was already planning how to report him for moderator attention, but fortunately he alread got banned.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle be sure about it ;) I'm continuously accumulating SO fails and I'm planning to send him a bigger bunch of it in these days.

Comment: If the link is on a website, it's the website's responsibility to encode it correctly.  If they don't do that, there's nothing you can do about it.  You really should have mentioned this in the question though.

Comment: Even though the question turns out to be on a different matter (server side encoding), I still find it worth noting that `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` is not entirely safe when attempting proper URL-encoding. It does, for example, not treat question-marks - so a get-parameter encoded using the mentioned method will still contain the unescaped question-mark.